# How to design a T flipflop with NAND gates in Verilog (structural design)?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, flipflop

From a typical circuit diagram of T flip flops made of 3- and 2-input NAND gates, I tried to implement it with this code but could not figure out why am I not getting any answer in output terminal (here `n3`).

```
module Nand3(
    input a,b,c,
    output y
);
    assign y = ~(a&b&c);
endmodule

module Nand2(
    input a,b,
    output y
);
    assign y = ~(a&b);
endmodule

// design of a t flipflop

module tff(
    input t1, reset, clk,
    output q
);
    wire n1, n2, n3, n4;
    Nand3 a1(n4, t1, clk, n1);
    Nand3 a2(n3, t1, clk, n2);
    Nand2 b1(n1, n4, n3);
    Nand2 b2(n2, n3, n4);
    assign q=n3;
    always@(*) $monitor("n1 = %b, n2 = %b, n3 = %b, n4 =%b", n1,n2,n3,n4); //to check i tried to print
endmodule
```

Initially n1, n2 are 1, but n3 = n4 = x remains.

Later I even tried to initialize the n3, n4 wires with:

```
assign n4=1'b0;
assign n3=1'b0;
```

but it didn't work.

Or is it any syntactical error because I am trying to achieve a reg type circuitry with wire type? (or anything related to that?

Comment: Since you are a new user: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You should never try to model a flip flop with NAND gates in Verilog.  You should always use the appropriate level of abstraction for a flip flop: behavioral modelling.  This avoids all the issues that you are encountering, especially simulation race conditions.

In addition to avoiding the known issues, this code is much easier to understand:

```
module tff(
    input t1, reset, clk,
    output reg q
);
    always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset) begin
            q <= 0;
        end else if (t1) begin
            q <= ~q;
        end
    end
endmodule

module tb;

bit clk;
bit reset = 1;
bit t1;
wire q;

tff dut (
    .clk    (clk),
    .reset  (reset),
    .t1     (t1),
    .q      (q)
);

always #5 clk++;

initial begin
    #12 reset = 0;
    repeat (5) @(posedge clk);
    t1 <= 1;
    repeat (10) @(posedge clk);
    t1 <= 0;
    repeat (10) @(posedge clk);
    $finish;
end

always @(negedge clk) $display($time, "  t1=%b q=%b", t1, q);

endmodule
```

Output:

```
          10  t1=0 q=0
          20  t1=0 q=0
          30  t1=0 q=0
          40  t1=0 q=0
          50  t1=0 q=0
          60  t1=1 q=0
          70  t1=1 q=1
          80  t1=1 q=0
          90  t1=1 q=1
         100  t1=1 q=0
         110  t1=1 q=1
         120  t1=1 q=0
         130  t1=1 q=1
         140  t1=1 q=0
         150  t1=1 q=1
         160  t1=0 q=0
         170  t1=0 q=0
         180  t1=0 q=0
         190  t1=0 q=0
         200  t1=0 q=0
         210  t1=0 q=0
         220  t1=0 q=0
         230  t1=0 q=0
         240  t1=0 q=0
         250  t1=0 q=0
```

[image: waves]

See also: [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/687252/72936)